# Looking for a simple way to make a raspberry pi3 Kiosk showing photos and videos from a USB stick

Tags: image-viewer, raspberry-pi, video-player, vlc, kiosk

I'm looking for a very basic and simple way to implement a kiosk with a `raspberry pi 3`. What I'd like to do is this: startup script that read the content of a USB stick and launch a software to display photos and videos in a loop. My totem is portrait mode, so I already added `display_rotate` to `boot/config.txt`.

The problem is that I cannot find a software capable to show both images and videos. I tried with VLC, which seems perfect for my goal, but It has a [bug](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/23048) with fullscreen in portrait mode. Omxplayer can't reproduce still images. I don't want anything that involves network connections, just read the content of a USB stick and display, that's it. Content can be images or videos (can be limited to certain format). Any idea?